# Cache Control in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching

Please see my htaccess file code below

```
# Begin cache control #
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresActive off
<FilesMatch ".*">
Header unset Cache-Control
Header unset Expires
Header unset Last-Modified
FileETag None
Header unset Pragma
</FilesMatch>
# End cache control #
```

Is this the correct code? We are having issue with users unable to see the updated website page. Its not the browser cache or cookie problem.